# Can nHibernate work with SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, compact-framework

I did a google search and found some forum threads explaining it won't work and some threads about people using it in .net compact framework 3.5/sql server compact edition 3.5  but having troubles.

So is it possible or am I being hopeful? I'm looking to use it on Windows Mobile 6.1...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how it works on Windows Mobile 6.1, but NHibernate works with SQLCE. We're using SQLCE40 and were using 3.5 before.
But as always, there are important things to regard with this edatabase engine, like the fact it only hanldes one transaction and no nested transactions. As well as the limited amount of data types.

You can use it with
*NHibernate.Dialect.MsSqlCeDialect* and *NHibernate.Driver.SqlServerCeDriver*